# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'RdylBu'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

This code is basically trying to plot the parallel coordinates. Since the outcome is continuous variable , to see the outcome pattern for each rows of data; shades need to be assign based on outcome. Book is using plot.cm.RdYlBu  for similar case but when I tried to use this, there was an attribute error.

here is the similar code from book

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from math import exp

target_url = ("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data")

#read abalone data
abalone = pd.read_csv(target_url,header=None, prefix="V")
abalone.columns = ['Sex', 'Length', 'Diameter', 'Height', 'Whole Wt', 'Shucked Wt', 'Viscera Wt', 'Shell Wt', 'Rings']

#get summary to use for scaling
summary = abalone.describe()
minRings = summary.iloc[3,7]
maxRings = summary.iloc[7,7]
nrows = len(abalone.index)

for i in range(nrows):
#plot rows of data as if they were series data
    dataRow = abalone.iloc[i,1:8]
    labelColor = (abalone.iloc[i,8] - minRings) / (maxRings - minRings)
    dataRow.plot(color=plot.cm.RdYlBu(labelColor), alpha=0.5)
plot.xlabel("Attribute Index")
plot.ylabel(("Attribute Values"))
plot.show()
```

Comment: It would help readability if you'd use the standard way to import: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  Maybe you're using a very old matplotlib version?  Maybe you reassigned `plot` to something else during earlier code?

Comment: Did you copy-paste the error into your title? If so, the error came from some other code where `RdylBu` was incorrectly capitalized.

Comment: Thanks for you comment  @JohanC  , looks like I was  using old version of matplotlib.